# Can't locate element - Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This was working for me a week or two ago but I think the website changed recently.

I am having trouble grabbing an element that I normally able to grab. I can't tell if its because of a frame issue, where I need to switch to a specific frame, or if I am not waiting for the correct element.

Here is a picture of the issue:
[image]

Here is the function in question:

```
def reset_email():
    time.sleep(1)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 15)
   browser_options.browser.get('https://cp.intermedia.net/ControlPanel/Menu/AccountMenu/?frameUrl=https://cp.intermedia.net/aspx/Exchange/')

    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 15)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlSearchOptions$txtSearch']")))
    except exceptions.TimeoutException as e:
        print("timed out") #IT USUALLY DOES TIME OUT HERE
        pass
    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlSearchOptions$txtSearch']") #IT FAILS HERE EVERYTIME
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(email_selection_only.email_select)

    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlSearchOptions_btnSearch')
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlUserList_rptList_ctl01_ctlRowContent__ctlActionMenu2_btnAction')
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlUserList_rptList_ctl01_ctlRowContent__ctlActionMenu2_rptMenuBlocks_ctl00_rptMenuItems_ctl00_btnMenuItem')
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_txtManualPassword"))))
    
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_txtManualPassword")
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_txtConfirmPassword")
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_btnOk')
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    return
```

The code fails here specifically:

```
im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlSearchOptions$txtSearch']")
```

It will say:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlSearchOptions$txtSearch']"}
```

**What I have tried:**

I notice two iframes in the webpage and I have tried both.
If I tried to use `browser_options.browser.switch_to_frame('frame-content')`

before I try to select the element I get:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: frame-content`

If I try `browser_options.browser.switch_to_frame('MainFrame')` that seems to work but I then get stuck on the error from before:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlSearchOptions$txtSearch']"}
```

From here I don't know what else to try. Here is the page source information just incase I am missing something: NOTE - The source information is over 30,000 character so I can't put it here. Instead I put it in a text file online so you can see it:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/10DWzA9-52H7qAQ6AYdtJMRnOZ3wK9O0a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If there are nested frames, you have to switch to the outer frame, then the inner frame, then access your content. I can't log in to the website and there's nothing there in your link -- so I'm not sure if this is what's going on.

Comment: WTFREAK happened to my text file? I will upload it somewhere else I guess

Comment: @C.Peck I was able to reupload it. Also I think you are right. I believe the `mainFrame` is above the `frame-content` iframe. I will check that out now and let you know

Comment: YES! I was able to get it done thanks to you @C.Peck. I am going to make an answer for it now.

Answer (score 0):

@c.Peck helped me find the answer with his statement. The key was to switch into the nested iframe of `frame-content` from the `MaineFrame` iframe.

Here is the code:

```
def reset_email():
    time.sleep(1)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 15)
    browser_options.browser.get('https://cp.intermedia.net/ControlPanel/Menu/AccountMenu/?frameUrl=https://cp.intermedia.net/aspx/Exchange/')
    browser_options.browser.switch_to_frame('MainFrame')
    time.sleep(1)
    browser_options.browser.switch_to_frame('frame-content')

    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlSearchOptions$txtSearch']")
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(email_selection_only.email_select)

    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlSearchOptions_btnSearch')
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlUserList_rptList_ctl01_ctlRowContent__ctlActionMenu2_btnAction')
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlUserList_rptList_ctl01_ctlRowContent__ctlActionMenu2_rptMenuBlocks_ctl00_rptMenuItems_ctl00_btnMenuItem')
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_txtManualPassword"))))
    
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_txtManualPassword")
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_txtConfirmPassword")
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(email_pd.pd)
    im_blacklistaddbutton = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_dlgResetPassword_btnOk')
    im_blacklistaddbutton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    return
```